# Renaming Sheets in Macro without renaming first four sheets

Tags: excel, renaming, vba

I know how to make marcos but during school he never taught me everything to do with them, mainly with the Dim. 
My questions is how to I make a marco that will rename all my sheets expect for the first four.

```
Sub RenameSheet()

    Dim rs As Worksheet

    For Each rs In Sheets
        rs.Name = rs.Range("D5")
    Next rs

End Sub
```

Works for every sheet but I dont want to be renaming every sheet. My first four are Documentation, Summarry, RONATemplate, KaycanTemplate. Which I want to leave has is. I cant really just put those names in cell D5 to make it work where its a template, and it will mess up my other marcos.

Answer (score 0):

First option is to use different kind of loop which iterates based on sheet index/number. Here is the code running only for `Worksheets Collection`:

```
Sub RenameSheet()

    Dim rs As Long

    For rs = 5 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(rs).Name = Worksheets(rs).Range("D5")
    Next rs

End Sub
```

Your loop starts as of 5th of worksheet and runs until the last one.

The other option is to exclude all sheets with names which you have mentioned in your question. In that situation you could run this macro:

```
Sub RenameSheet()

    Dim rs As Worksheet

    For Each rs In Sheets
        if rs.name <> "Summary" And rs.Name <> "RONATemplate" and rs.Name <> "KeycanTemplate" Then
            rs.Name = rs.Range("D5")
        end if
    Next rs

End Sub
```

However, keep in mind that all conditional checks like `rs.Name <> "Summary"` are case sensitive therefore you need to put appropriate names within code including upper- and lower- cases. Or you could use `UCase` function to compare to capitalized names like:

```
if UCase(rs.Name) <> "SUMMARY" And UCase(rs.Name) <> "RONATEMPLATE" And Ucase(rs.Name) <> "KEYCANTEMPLATE" Then
```

I would suggest to use second type of improved procedure. If you change the order of your sheets (e.g. move first sheet into 6th position) you will get unexpected results running first `For i=1` loop. There is not such problem running second type of loop/subroutine.

Comment: `For rs = 5 In Sheets.Count` should be `For rs = 5 to Sheets.Count` of course.

Comment: The other thing, I'd point out is if there are any chart `Sheets` you'll get a 438 runtime error on the first one as chart sheets have no `range` object.

Comment: that's obviously right therefore 2nd idea is much better also considering other problems (like sheet order reorganisation).

Answer (score 0):

You could create kind of a blacklist with and check if `rs.Name` is one of the names you do not want to change or you could access the sheets by index.

i.e.

```
For i = 5 to Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).Name = rs.Range("D5")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To change every sheet after the 4th use the index property of sheets in an if statement:

```
Sub RenameSheet()

Dim rs As Worksheet

For Each rs In Sheets
    If rs.Index > 4 Then
        rs.Name = rs.Range("D5")
    End If
Next rs

End Sub
```