# Renaming only certain sheets with Macro

Tags: excel, vba, names

I'm trying to find a macro that will only rename certain sheets based on a cell, and use that same cell in other sheets for other purposes.  I've seen two macro functions.  One that tells it to start on a specific nth sheet of the workbook.  Another one tells it to only rename certain sheets.  Both options have problems.  What if you want to add sheets?  Then your first hot sheet won't be the same nth sheet as before.  It could be the 11th sheet now instead of the 5th sheet.  Your macro will need to be updated, which defeats the purpose of this whole thing. As for the second option, just listing all the sheets you want to rename: What do you do after you run your macro the first time?  The sheet names in the macro will need to be updated to reflect what your new sheet names are, also defeating the purpose of this whole thing.

I tried running the macro by the vba sheet name rather than the lay sheet name.  And it still won't work.

```
Sub h100_monthyear()        
    Dim rs As Worksheet
    For Each rs In Sheets  
        If x01st.select <> And x02nd.select <> And x03rd.select <> And x04th.select <> And x05th.select <> And x06th.select <> And x07th.select <> And x08th.select <> And x09th.select <> And x10th.select <> And x11th.select <> And x12th.select <> And x13th.select <> And x14th.select <> And x15th.select <> And x16th.select <> And x17th.select <> And x18th.select <> And x19th.select <> And x20th.select <> And x21st.select <> And x22nd.select <> And x23rd.select <> And x24th.select <> And x25th.select <> And x26th.select <> And x27th.select <> And x28th.select <> And x29th.select <> And x30th.select <> And x31st.select <> Then     
            rs.Name = rs.Range("h100") 
    Next rs
End Sub
```

I couldn't get any other solutions from this thread [Renaming Sheets in Macro without renaming first four sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750124/renaming-sheets-in-macro-without-renaming-first-four-sheets) and I got yelled at by David (site manager) for trying to post there.  Users beware, apparently you have to be careful where you post certain things.

For quick reference, here's the most basic macro that the above is based on:

```
Sub h100_monthyear()
    Dim rs As Worksheet 
    For Each rs In Sheets
        rs.Name = rs.Range("h100")
    Next rs 
End Sub
```

I also tried it with the VBA sheet names in this fashion:

```
x01st <> And x02nd <> And x03rd <> And x04th <> And x05th <> And x06th <> And x07th <> And x08th <> And x09th <> And x10th <> And x11th <> And x12th <> And x13th <> And x14th <> And x15th <> And x16th <> And x17th <> And x18th <> And x19th <> And x20th <> And x21st <> And x22nd <> And x23rd <> And x24th <> And x25th <> And x26th <> And x27th <> And x28th <> And x29th <> And x30th <> And x31st <> Then
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that this `If x01st.select <> And x02nd.select <> And x03rd.select <> And x04th.select …` is no valid syntax.

I suggest to put all the names of the worksheets that are allowed to be renamed into an array `WsNameList` and check in your loop if the name of the current worksheet `rs.Name` is in the `WsNameList`. Therefore I used the function `IsInArray`.

```
Sub h100_monthyear()
    Dim WsNameList As Variant
    WsNameList = Array("x01st", "x02nd", "x03rd", "x04th", "x05th") 'add more sheets here

    Dim rs As Worksheet
    For Each rs In Worksheets
        If IsInArray(rs.Name, WsNameList) Then
            rs.Name = rs.Range("h100")
        End If
    Next rs
End Sub

Public Function IsInArray(ByVal FindString As String, ByVal InArray As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(InArray, FindString)) > -1)
End Function
```

---

Alternatively (without an array list)

```
Sub h100_monthyear_ALTERNATIVE()
    Dim rs As Worksheet
    For Each rs In Worksheets
        If rs.Name = "x01st" Or rs.Name = "x02nd" Or rs.Name = "x03rd" Or _
           (rs.Name Like "x??th" And Val(Mid(rs.Name, 2, 2)) >= 4 And Val(Mid(rs.Name, 2, 2)) <= 31) Then
            rs.Name = rs.Range("h100")
        End If
    Next rs
End Sub
```